# How to manipulate matrix addition and multiplication for Euclidean distance computation?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, euclidean-distance, norm

I have the following:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4  5 6; 7 8 9];
B = [10 11 12; 13 14 15];

[N1, D1] = size(A);
[N2, D2] = size(B);

A_sq = sum(A.^2, 2);
B_sq = sum(B.^2, 2)';
D = A_sq(:,ones(1,N2)) + B_sq(ones(1,N1),:) - 2.*(A*B');
```

where **D** is **N1 x D1** matrix.

I want to write expression for D in one single step, i.e., something like this (this is for illustration purpose, but it should compute the same Euclidean distance as the code above):

```
D = sum(A - B).^2;
```

I will appreciate any advise.

Comment: This code is somewhat hard to follow - what Euclidean distance are you trying to calculate?

Comment: It is in k-means clustering to compute distance between data points and centroids. A has more rows than B, but both have the same dimension.

Comment: OK so distance between each vector in A and each vector in B?

Comment: Yes. As expression D = A_sq(:,ones(1,N2)) + B_sq(ones(1,N1),:) - 2.*(A*B'); computes it. But I would like to write it in this form sum(. . .).^2, i.e., sum appears only once or not at all. I do not want to use for loop either.

Comment: I deleted my answer: `D = repmat(sum(A'.^2)', 1, size(B,1)) + repmat(sum(B'.^2), size(A,1), 1) - 2.*(A*B');`. Please revise your question, it's really hard to understand what you are looking for. What do you mean: **"compute the same Euclidean distance as the code above"** ?

Comment: By same, I meant that if you ran my given example, your solution code should give the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox you can use [`pdist2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html), which does just that:

```
D = pdist2(A,B).^2
```

Or you can do it manually with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
D = permute((sum(bsxfun(@minus, A, permute(B, [3 2 1])).^2,2)), [1 3 2]);
```

For your example matrices

```
A = [1 2 3; 4  5 6; 7 8 9];
B = [10 11 12; 13 14 15];
```

either of the above gives

```
D =
   243   432
   108   243
    27   108
```